# Strange transition behavior for inline elements styles in certain places

Tags: javascript, css

**This is a jsfiddle example file that replicates the problem:** https://jsfiddle.net/Lhr0d6cw/11/

I wanted the element (when clicked) to expand for 6seconds from its original position but notice that when you click the red card (or any card), it doesn't start expanding from the originals position it used to be, but rather from the middle, I assume that its because `transition` of 6s to `top` and `left` is not being applied for some reason.

Only places I was able to make it work properly so far are stackoverflow editor below or by inserting a debugger in the code and doing it manually but when using my localhost or jsfiddle it doesn't transition properly.

**This is the same example on stackoverflow which works as desired:**

```js
const productCards = document.querySelectorAll(".products__card");

productCards.forEach(c => {
  // console.log("clicked1");
  c.addEventListener("click", openCard)
});

function openCard(e) {

  console.log("clicked");
  console.dir(this);
  let top = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let left = this.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  // this.style.transition = "top 0.9s, left 0.9s";
  this.style.top = top + "px";
  this.style.left = left + "px";
  this.style.position = "fixed";
  console.log(`top: ${top}, left: ${left}`);
  // debugger;
  this.classList.add("open");
}
```

```css
.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.products .products__card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(1);
  /* box-shadow: 3px 7px 55px -10px c(very-light); */
  transition: width 0.9s, height 0.9s, z-index 0.9s, top 6s, left 6s;
}

.products .products__card.card-1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.products .products__card.card-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.products .products__card.card-3 {
  background-color: green;
}

.products .products__card.card-4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.products .products__card.card-5 {
  background-color: pink;
}

.products .products__card.card-6 {
  background-color: gray;
}

.products .products__card.open {
  width: 550px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 50% !important;
  left: 50% !important;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
  z-index: 120;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1000px 1000px c(box-overlay);
}
```

```html
<div class="products">

  <div class="products__card card-1">

  </div>
  <div class="products__card card-2">

  </div>
  <div class="products__card card-3">

  </div>
  <div class="products__card card-4">

  </div>
  <div class="products__card card-5">

  </div>
  <div class="products__card card-6">

  </div>
</div>
```

**works when debugging:**

The strange thing as mentioned above is that my problem in the browser using localhost is also solved when I insert debugger in the code and manually skip through the last step of adding `.open` class. If you have the same problem in jsfiddle or your own editor, try adding `debugger;` before  `this.classList.add("open");` and then open the console and then click the card and go over the last step manually in the console. you will notice that the card expanded from its original place as desired taking 6s to finish which means the transition was applied in this case.

**My questions:**

Why is `transition` for `top` and `left` only working in certain environments? is it a browser problem? I'm using the latest chrome. does someone know of a better way to achieve the same results?

**code comments:**
-obviously, 6 seconds is not what I will be using in my code, its used here just to make the transition obvious.

-In my source code, you can see that because I can't transition from `position static` to `position fixed` I had to use Javascript to add `position fixed` style inline to the element before the `.open` class is added, that way `transition` can take place properly when `.open` is added.

-I also added `top` and `left` values inline to keep the card in its original place when `position: fixed` style is applied because as you might know fixed position takes the element out of its flow, so top and left keep it in place.

-I added !important in css `.open` class because without it I can't override inline css as you might also know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem just now by applying a little hack. It seems that in some environments (localhost, jsfiddle) the javascript engine is adding the .open class faster than expected and the fact that it is working fine when debugging (slow process) indicated that to me. so I added a `setTimeout()` to the last piece of code delayed it by 20. this solved my problem and now it works fine on JSfiddle and on my computer. here is the new edited sample that works:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhr0d6cw/14/

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.classList.add("open");
}, 20);
```

I would still like to know if there is a better way of doing this animation if someone would like to share!